# TeXStudio error messages just say "Process exited with error(s)" without any other information

Tags: errors, texstudio, overleaf, compilation-error

I have the following issue with TeXStudio: Whenever it detects an error, it simply says "Process exited with error(s)." That's it--no explanation, no line number where the error occurred, nothing. Actually I used to get more informative error messages until about a year ago when I did something that screwed it up, somehow. (I don't remember exactly what I did/when I did it, but it was around the time when I adjusted some settings so that all output files other than the .pdf and .tex files would be grouped into a single folder upon compilation. Though to be honest, I'm not entirely sure that these two things are at all related...I'm just speculating here.)

To illustrate my issue further, here's a comparison of the error messages between Overleaf and TexStudio:

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Test}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
$a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{document}
```

**Overleaf Error Message:**

[image]

**TexStudio Error Message:**

[image]

I know that TexStudio and Overleaf are not going to have the same exact error messages, but the pictures above are to illustrate just how useless the TexStudio message is, while the Overleaf message is helpful is pointing out the error and makes a suggestion to correct it. TexStudio used to give similar error messages, and I'd like to know how I can get them back. Does anyone know how I fix it?

Edit: The log tab is also blank :(
[image]

Comment: Click the "log" tab in your last image and you will see the extracted pieces of error/warning messages. That "log" tab is expected to be auto focused when compilation completes.

Comment: The "log" tab is blank, unfortunately. I edited the post to include a picture.

Comment: what are you using to compile? miktex + texify?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Uhh, when I go to Options -->Configure TexStudio it says "txs:///pdflatex" in the Default Compiler field. So I guess pdflatex?

Comment: well you should try to know more about your tex system. texstudio in only an editor and can you only show what the tex system provides.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: After going to Help -> Check System Installation, I got a report that included the following snippet at the top: "PDFLATEX: pdflatex.exe -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6839 (1.40.19) (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2018 Han The Thanh..." So does this indicate that my editor is MiKTeX? or MiKTeX-pdfTeX or something? (I downloaded TexStudio like 5 years ago, so I kind of forgot the details of how exactly I set it up, and what the compiler it uses...)

Comment: The problem might come from the option `--aux-directory=build` following `pdflatex`. With this option applied, the log file is written to sub-directory `build`. You need to configure TeXstudio to also search for log file in that directory, see [this wiki](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks#using-a-separate-directory-for-auxiliary-files).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ: You correctly identified the problem! Thank you! I just solved it by going to Options --> Configure TexStudio --> Build, and then in the Log File field I typed "build" and hit OK. Problem solved!!

Answer (score 1):

The  message I get with TeXstudio 3.0.1 and 2.12.10 is the same. Look at the `Log File` tab.

Could you please try the portable version 3.0.1 to see if there is any difference?

[image: 14]

Comment: See @muzimuzhiZ's comment and my reply. The issue was that I needed to tell TexStudio where to search for the log file. I had previously configured it so that all the auxiliary files, including the log file, were saved to a separate folder called "build." I hadn't specified where TexStudio could look, so it wasn't able to find the file.