# TexStudio reports "Process exited with error(s)" but there is no error message

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

Something happened between yesterday and today (I don't know what) and now I can't build my text document.  Unfortunately the error message is not very clear:

lang-none

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "conference_101719".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

This is similar to this question which doesn't have an answer:

- [TeXStudio error messages just say "Process exited with error(s)" without any other information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574762/179342)

Under Log I have this but these are just warnings I think:

```
Citation `widell2010reducing' on page 1 undefined
Citation `korkmaz2023safe' on page 1 undefined
Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined
Reference `tb:poly-funcs' on page 2 undefined
Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined
Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined
```

I also have a warning at the bottom of the pdf viewer pane, but this is not surprising:

```
Failed to find file "/Users/...pdf"; perhaps it has been deleted.
```

I checked and pdflatex is still in that location and runs from the command line:

```
(base) ... $ /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

How do I debug this to figure out what went wrong?

I am using an old version (4.2.3) of Tex Studio because 4.5.1 is not supported on my OS (OS X 10.15.7).

***MORE INFO***

Here is the full log file as requested by @DavidCarlisle:

```
$ cat conference_101719.log
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.3)  28 MAR 2023 14:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**conference_101719.tex
(./conference_101719.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (./IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen138
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen139
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen140
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count185
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count186
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count187
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks16
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ptm on input line 5
03.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen141
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen142
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen143
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen145
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen146
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen147
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen148
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen149
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen150
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen151
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen152
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen153
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen154
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen155
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip47
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count195
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count196
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count197
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen156
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen157
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen158
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen159
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count198
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box50
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen160
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen161
\c@IEEEbiography=\count199
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box51
)
** ATTENTION: Overriding command lockouts (line 2).
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 302.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 332.
Package: cite 2015/02/27  v 5.5
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen162
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen163
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count267
\leftroot@=\count268
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count269
\DOTSCASE@=\count270
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
\big@size=\dimen164
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count271
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count272
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count273
\dspbrk@lvl=\count274
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count275
\column@=\count276
\maxfields@=\count277
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen165
\alignsep@=\dimen166
\tagshift@=\dimen167
\tagwidth@=\dimen168
\totwidth@=\dimen169
\lineht@=\dimen170
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty
Package: algorithmic 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic'

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks22
)
\c@ALC@unique=\count278
\c@ALC@line=\count279
\c@ALC@rem=\count280
\c@ALC@depth=\count281
\ALC@tlm=\skip53
\algorithmicindent=\skip54
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen171
\Gin@req@width=\dimen172
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count282
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box54
)
(./conference_101719.aux)
\openout1 = `conference_101719.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.

-- Lines per column: 56 (exact).
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count283
\scratchdimen=\dimen173
\scratchbox=\box55
\nofMPsegments=\count284
\nofMParguments=\count285
\everyMPshowfont=\toks23
\MPscratchCnt=\count286
\MPscratchDim=\dimen174
\MPnumerator=\count287
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count288
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks24
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <11> on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 36.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 36.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `widell2010reducing' on page 1 undefined on input line 
67.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `korkmaz2023safe' on page 1 undefined on input line 67.


<images/refrig_diagram.pdf, id=1, 250.9375pt x 160.6pt>
File: images/refrig_diagram.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use images/refrig_diagram.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: images/refrig_diagram.pdf  used on input line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 216.81pt x 138.76514pt.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}


 <./images/refrig_diagram.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined on input line 95
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `tb:poly-funcs' on page 2 undefined on input line 95.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined on input line 97
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:comp-curves' on page 2 undefined on input line 97
.


!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/comp_curves_pow_sp_3
-5in.pdf): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: show the full `.log` file not a summary from the editor

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the log file. Indeed, one of the image files was an empty file (0 bytes).  I wish it had reported that in the error window!

Comment: oooh you crashed pdftex...  something strange about ./images/comp_curves_pow_sp_3
-5in.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As explained by @David Carlisle, the messages window is a summary of the error messages. To see the full log of messages, find the .log file and look in there for the actual error message.

In my case it was

```
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./images/comp_curves_pow_sp_3
-5in.pdf): reading image file failed
```

I had accidentally replaced the original image file with a corrupt one that was blank (0 bytes).